# How to counter Labrynth Labyrinth?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

I see some players play Labrynth Labyrinth. The deck simply destroys/negates everything I have and still manages to easily recover more cards from their deck/GY. I have no idea what's their weakness. Neither google helps (I guess the archtype is new..?)

Comment: It's not so clear if you ask about the card itself "Labrynth Labyrinth", which is a Field Card, or the Archetype Labyrinth in general

Comment: @DarkCygnus Sorry, thought that was clear. I'm asking about the archtype.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Labrynth is indeed a newer Archetype (03-2022 OCG, 08-2022 TCG) and is considered one of the best if not the best Trap-Archetype currently in the game.
It's a Trap-based control deck which get's stronger, the longer the duel goes.
The main strategy is to control the field with generic normal trap cards while you control Lovely Labrynth of the Silver Castle.

So the main weaknesses are:

**Spell & Trap destruction**
Like most Backrow-heavy decks, Labrynth are weak to any kind of backrow hate. They don't have the best recovery game (still good for a trap deck), so if you keep hitting the backrow, they are way to slow against most decks.
Especially Cosmic Cyclone (or any backrow removal that banishes) is strong, since they can't recycle their banished trap cards.

**Keep off Labrynth of the Silver Castle**
It is recovery, beater and disruptor in one card. It's the main card of the deck. Negate her effects or banish her to weaken the deck. Without the field spell, it's also good to bounce her back to the hand.

**Play aggressive or go 1st**
Labrynth is the weakest in the early stages of the game. They are very weak against established boards (going 2nd). If you can overwhelm them early, they usually loose the game.

**Key Cards**
The main cards you have to get rid of as fast as you can:

- Welcome Labrynth (Summon the boss monster from the deck)
- Labrynth Labyrinth (Recover & Desruption)
- Lovely Labrynth of the Silver Castle (Main Bossmonster)

*Things to consider*
Like in all TCGs, you have a harder time with certain deck strategies than others. If you also play a backrow-heavy control deck, chances are, labrynth is faster and will most of the time beat you.
I currently play Crystal Beast Conclave Control with great success, but I never won a game against Labrynth. It's just faster in controlling the board than I am.

I always recommend to try and play a deck you struggle against yourself to learn how it works, where it weakspots are and to generally understand it better. Free simulators like EDOPro, YGOmega or also Duellingbook are a great way to learn a new deck for free.